# spring-restdocs 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT maven is not generating the adoc files

Tags: spring-restdocs

I followed the testng sample of *spring-restdocs 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT*. I am able to generate the adoc file through gradle. But when I am using the maven its not generating the doc files.

Mmy **pom.xml** has the following details:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*TestNgApplicationTests.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-docs</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <backend>html</backend>
                <doctype>book</doctype>
                <attributes>
                    <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets> 
                </attributes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/docs</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Where are your `.adoc` files located? The Maven Asciidoctor plugin uses a different default location to the Gradle Asciidoctor plugin

Answer (score 2):

Try to run using this command from your terminal:

```
$> mvn package
```

- The generated files should be under `/target`.

  - generated **snippets** should be under `/target/generated-snippets`.
  - generated **.html** should be under `/target/generated-docs`.

Make sure you have your generated-snippets directory configured to **/target** directory on your test class:

```
@Rule
public RestDocumentation restDocumentation = 
    new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");
```

Comment: Thanks , previously I was running with TestNG test cases which are not generating the docs , but with the latest restdocs versions its able to generate the docs